# Nginx as reverse proxy django gunicorn returning 400 bad request

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to use nginx as a reverse proxy to receive incoming calls, then,  depending on the server_name, redirect those calls to different computers (hosts), running nginx Django and Gunicorn. So far, I've tried different configurations for the conf file on the host, but none of them are working. Is there anything wrong with my conf files?

This is the nginx.conf in 192.168.0.13 that will function as a reverse proxy:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.coding.test;

  location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.8:80;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        # app1 reverse proxy follow
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
```

This is the nginx.conf in 192.168.0.8 that is intended to run the django app:

```
upstream django {
    server unix:///home/pi/coding-in-dfw/mysocket.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name www.coding.test

    client_max_body_size 4G;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location /static/ {
        alias   /home/pi/coding-in-dfw/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias   /home/pi/coding-in-dfw/media/;
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
         uwsgi_pass  django;
         include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
     }
     location /.well-known {
         alias /home/pi/coding-in-dfw/.well-known;
     }
}
```

Finally this is the way I'm running gunicorn:

```
gunicorn --workers 5 --bind unix:///home/pi/coding-in-dfw/mysocket.sock codingindfw.wsgi:application && sudo service nginx restart
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do the logs say ?

Comment: There is no error or access log entry in the reverse proxy. But I got this error in the host server running gunicorn:

2019/02/01 20:12:51 [error] 32500#32500: *3 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.0.13, server: www.coding.test, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/home/pi/coding-in-dfw/mysocket.sock:", host: "www.coding.test"

What could be causing this error?  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I figured what I had to do, the solution in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53772810/can-i-use-nginx-as-reverse-proxy-in-this-particular-case)